# Offline encryption package for Chromebook

Tags: offline, security, encryption, chrome-os

I am looking for a local encryption package that will work on a Chromebook.

The aim is to have a file stored on the Chromebook or an attached SD/USB device.  Viewing the file will require entry of a password.

The package should operate with the Chromebook offline.  Every possible solution I have seen so far requires an internet connection and operates on files that are stored in the cloud.

Freeware would be nice but I'm quite willing to pay for it.

Comment: Are you comfortable with entering Developer Mode and using a [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) chroot?